# Автоматическое игнорирование регистра букв при поиске

Tags: vim

Как в *Vim* при поиске (команда `/`) автоматически
игнорировать регистр букв (заглавные или строчные)?  Я знаю про
`\c`, но хотелось бы, чтобы это работало автоматически.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для этого есть две опции.  Опция
[`ignorecase`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27ignorecase%27)
позволяет всегда игнорировать регистр. Опция
[`smartcase`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27smartcase%27)
игнорирует регистр, если ваш запрос не содержит заглавных.
То есть, если вы ищете `foo`, то будут найдены
`foo`, `Foo`, `fOo`, итд;
а если вы ищете `Foo`, то будет искаться
только `Foo`. Чтобы опция `smartcase`
заработала, опция `ignorecase` тоже должна
быть включена.

Стоит помнить, что настройка `ignorecase` также
влияет на поведение операторов `==` и `!=`
и поиска по тегам. Операторы сравнения можно заменить
на `==#` и `!=#` соответственно,
как рекомендуют
[некоторые руководства](https://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/22.html#case-sensitivity). Поведение
поиска тегов можно настроить с помощью настройки 
[`tagcase`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27tagcase%27).

Comment: Похоже, эти опции влияют на поиск не только командой `/`. Также меняется поведение простых операторов сравнения строк `==`, `!=` и других, команда `:tag` может начать вести себя иначе.

Comment: @mymedia  Спасибо, вы правы.  Добавил про это поведение и как его избежать.